# Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml

getting this error and i am not able to figure it out 
i am not getting where the error is occuring. i am not using any image 
 in imageview from drawable folder

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smtrick.smartnanded_user, PID: 23258
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating 
    class 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:811)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:884)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:845)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:887)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:845)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at

androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)  E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20871)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6268)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2972)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2487)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1580)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7634)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:958)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:770)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:702)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:944)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:927)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown layout animation name: set
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createLayoutAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:262)
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createLayoutAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:237)
        at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:218)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.initFromAttributes(ViewGroup.java:719)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:663)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:92)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:87)
        at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:121)
        at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.(CardView.java:117)
            ... 69 more
     I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23258 SIG: 9

```
My xmml File

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_right_to_left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgProduct"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgraycolor"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

       </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>

Comment: evrything is right

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed which attribute that was for. You need to create one more animation file for the `<layoutAnimation>`, and have that point to your custom animation. That `<layoutAnimation>` file is what you would use on your `<CardView>`, then. There's an example on the linked duplicate.